# LinearLayout not redrawing after invalidate

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following LinearLayout in which I'm dynamically inserting views:

```
        <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/loyaltycardlist"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:background="#00f"
              android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

and the Java code:

```
LinearLayout loyaltyCardLL = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.loyaltycardinfo);
for(MyCard thisCardNode : mLoyaltyCards)
{
    LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.activity_view_node_details_loyaltycard, null);

    item.setTag(thisCardNode);

    TextView tv = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.loyaltycard_item_title);
    tv.setText(thisCardNode.getTitle());

    ... etc

    loyaltyCardLL.addView(item);
}

loyaltyCardLL.invalidate();
```

The containing linear layout never expands to hold the layouts I've added, even though I'm calling `invalidate()`.

And tips on why this is happening?

Comment: try adding `item` with `layoutParam`. `loyaltyCardLL.addView(item, new LayoutParam(LayoutParam.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParam.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Comment: Your Id for LinearLayout is `loyaltycardlist` while you are adding views to `loyaltycardinfo` id.

Comment: @Pr38y that was it. The ID was wrong. Care to make it an answer?